# How to define actions in page object modeling

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am newbee to selenium. I was trying to access menu->sub-menu in PageObject Modeling.

My requirement is to click on Menu item and sub-menu item which appears dynamically.

I was going through StackOverflow and in one of the resolutions it was mentioned to write Actions as

```
      Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.moveToElement(currentOpenings).build().perform();
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10); 
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ausJobsSubmenu));
```

However i can't pass driver in constructor. if I pass constructor i am getting problem while running this script.  The error is below

```
FAILED: checkLinks java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method HomePageLinksClick(WebDriver) in the type HomePageLinksTest is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

If I include WebDriver driver in constructor as a parameter, my page class is not accepting that as parameter. Can anyone help?

**Page Class**

```
package au.com.sreetechconsulting.Pages;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import au.com.sreetechconsulting.TestCases.HomePageLinksTest;
public class HomePage {
 public WebDriver driver;
 @BeforeTest
 public void openBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.get("http://www.sreetechconsulting.com.au/");
}
@Test 
public void checkLinks() {
    HomePageLinksTest linkClick = new HomePageLinksTest(driver);

    linkClick.HomePageLinksClick();

 }
}
```

**Test Page Class**

```
package au.com.sreetechconsulting.TestCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class HomePageLinksTest {

  @FindBy(css="#header > div.container > div > div.col-md-9.main-nav > nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a")
 private WebElement currentOpenings;

  @FindBy(css="#header > div.container > div > div.col-md-9.main-nav > nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a")
  private WebElement ausJobsSubmenu;

  public HomePageLinksTest (WebDriver driver) {
     PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

  }

  public void HomePageLinksClick() {


   //currentOpenings.click();
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(currentOpenings).build().perform();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ausJobsSubmenu));
  }

}
```

Comment: Post the constructor and how you are trying to invoke it.

Comment: @Guy please see edited question above

Comment: In the class HomePageLinksTest define global `static WebDriver driver;` and in your constructor the first line should be `HomePageLinksTest.driver = driver;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the `driver` as a class member from the constructor

```
public class HomePageLinksTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public HomePageLinksTest (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void HomePageLinksClick() {
        //currentOpenings.click();
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(currentOpenings).build().perform();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10); 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ausJobsSubmenu));
    }
}
```

And in the test use it like this

```
@Test 
public void checkLinks() {
    HomePageLinksTest linkClick = new HomePageLinksTest(driver);
    linkClick.HomePageLinksClick();
 }
```